# Code does not print in the right format

Tags: python

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Player Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
print(title)
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    points = int(item[2]) * 3
    if points != 0:
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3],points)
        print(result)
```

Hi there just need a little help with those who knows how to use .format properly, for some reason when the answers are printed. I would expect this.

```
Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points 
Leeroy               19                   7                    12                   21
```

But the displayed output I get is this

```
    Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points              
Leeroy               19                   7                    12
                                   21
```

21 is being displayed in the wrong place. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a '\n' after the field 'Mathes Lost' 12. Did you just paste the output here? If so, you may need to show us the content of original input file to provide more infomation :)

Comment: no I wrote that out
heres the output
`Player Nickname      Matches Played       Matches Won          Matches Lost         Points              
Leeroy               19                   7                    12
                                   21`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to guess the best amount of spacing for each column, you could write a little function (called `write_cols()`) to calculate the widest entry in each column and then automatically space things accordingly:

```
def write_cols(data):
    col_spacer = "   "      # added between columns
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    return [col_spacer.join("{:<{width}}".format(col, width=widths[index]) for index, col in enumerate(row)) for row in data]


data = [['Player Nickname', 'Matches Played', 'Matches Won', 'Matches Lost', 'Points']]

with open('Results.txt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        items = line.strip().split(',')
        points = int(items[2]) * 3

        if points != 0:
            data.append([items[0], items[1], items[2], items[3], points])

    for line in write_cols(data):
        print(line)
```

This would display:

```
Player Nickname   Matches Played   Matches Won   Matches Lost   Points
Leeroy            19               7             12             21
```

The idea is to first create a list containing all of your data, including your header line and pass it to the function. This then calculates the widest entry in each column and uses this to add the correct amount of spacing to all entries. Finally, an extra two spaces are added between the columns.